# Slow PHP Script YoutubeAPI

Tags: php, performance

This script have very long loading times.

If i refresh my page it takes 3.5 seconds to load up this script.

What can causes this?

```
<?php
//Instagram Getter

// use this instagram access token generator http://instagram.pixelunion.net/
$access_token="";
$photo_count=9;

$json_instalink="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=$access_token&count=$photo_count";
$jsoninsta = file_get_contents($json_instalink);
$objinsta = json_decode($jsoninsta);

//Link zu den Bildern
$imagelink1 = $objinsta->data[0]->link;
$imagelink2 = $objinsta->data[1]->link;
$imagelink3 = $objinsta->data[2]->link;
$imagelink4 = $objinsta->data[3]->link;
$imagelink5 = $objinsta->data[4]->link;
$imagelink6 = $objinsta->data[5]->link;
$imagelink7 = $objinsta->data[6]->link;
$imagelink8 = $objinsta->data[7]->link;
$imagelink9 = $objinsta->data[8]->link;


//Das Bild an sich
$profilelink1 = $objinsta->data[0]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink2 = $objinsta->data[1]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink3 = $objinsta->data[2]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink4 = $objinsta->data[3]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink5 = $objinsta->data[4]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink6 = $objinsta->data[5]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink7 = $objinsta->data[6]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink8 = $objinsta->data[7]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink9 = $objinsta->data[8]->images->standard_resolution->url;

//Channel and API Key
$channel_id = '';
$api_key = '';



//Channel Statistics
$json_statsurl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=$channel_id&key=$api_key";
$jsonstats = file_get_contents($json_statsurl);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonstats);
$subscriberCount = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->subscriberCount;



//Last Video
$json_lastvidurl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=$api_key&channelId=$channel_id&part=id&order=date&maxResults=1";
$jsonlastvid = file_get_contents($json_lastvidurl);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid);
$lastvidid = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->id->videoId;

//Last Video Views
$json_lastvidstatsurl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$lastvidid&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvidstats = file_get_contents($json_lastvidstatsurl);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvidstats);
$lastvidviews = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

//Last Video Published Date
$json_lastvidinfourl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$lastvidid&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvidinfo = file_get_contents($json_lastvidinfourl);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvidinfo);
$lastvidtitle = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->title;
$lastvidpublished = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;


//Playlist Videos 9

$json_9vidurl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=$api_key&channelId=$channel_id&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=10";
$json9vid = file_get_contents($json_9vidurl);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($json9vid);
$vid0=$listFromYouTube->items[1]->id->videoId;
$vid1=$listFromYouTube->items[2]->id->videoId;
$vid2=$listFromYouTube->items[3]->id->videoId;
$vid3=$listFromYouTube->items[4]->id->videoId;
$vid4=$listFromYouTube->items[5]->id->videoId;
$vid5=$listFromYouTube->items[6]->id->videoId;
$vid6=$listFromYouTube->items[7]->id->videoId;
$vid7=$listFromYouTube->items[8]->id->videoId;
$vid8=$listFromYouTube->items[9]->id->videoId;


$watchlink="http://undercover-gaming.de/youtube/video/";

// TITLE PART
$vid0t=$listFromYouTube->items[1]->snippet->title;
$vid1t=$listFromYouTube->items[2]->snippet->title;
$vid2t=$listFromYouTube->items[3]->snippet->title;
$vid3t=$listFromYouTube->items[4]->snippet->title;
$vid4t=$listFromYouTube->items[5]->snippet->title;
$vid5t=$listFromYouTube->items[6]->snippet->title;
$vid6t=$listFromYouTube->items[7]->snippet->title;
$vid7t=$listFromYouTube->items[8]->snippet->title;
$vid8t=$listFromYouTube->items[9]->snippet->title;

// PUBLISH PART
$json_vid0url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vid0&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvid0 = file_get_contents($json_vid0url);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid0);
$vid0published = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;

$json_vid1url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vid1&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvid1 = file_get_contents($json_vid1url);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid1);
$vid1published = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;

$json_vid2url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vid2&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvid2 = file_get_contents($json_vid2url);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid2);
$vid2published = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;

$json_vid3url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vid3&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvid3 = file_get_contents($json_vid3url);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid3);
$vid3published = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;

$json_vid4url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vid4&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvid4 = file_get_contents($json_vid4url);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid4);
$vid4published = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;

$json_vid5url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vid5&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvid5 = file_get_contents($json_vid5url);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid5);
$vid5published = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;

$json_vid6url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vid6&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvid6 = file_get_contents($json_vid6url);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid6);
$vid6published = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;

$json_vid7url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vid7&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvid7 = file_get_contents($json_vid7url);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid7);
$vid7published = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;

$json_vid8url="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vid8&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvid8 = file_get_contents($json_vid8url);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid8);
$vid8published = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;

//VIEW PART 0-8
$json_viewgetter="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$vid0&key=$api_key";
$jsonplaylistgetter = file_get_contents($json_viewgetter);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonplaylistgetter);
$vid0views=$listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

$json_viewgetter1="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$vid1&key=$api_key";
$jsonplaylistgetter1 = file_get_contents($json_viewgetter1);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonplaylistgetter1);
$vid1views=$listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

$json_viewgetter2="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$vid2&key=$api_key";
$jsonplaylistgetter2 = file_get_contents($json_viewgetter2);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonplaylistgetter2);
$vid2views=$listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

$json_viewgetter3="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$vid3&key=$api_key";
$jsonplaylistgetter3 = file_get_contents($json_viewgetter3);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonplaylistgetter);
$vid3views=$listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

$json_viewgetter4="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$vid4&key=$api_key";
$jsonplaylistgetter4 = file_get_contents($json_viewgetter4);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonplaylistgetter4);
$vid4views=$listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

$json_viewgetter5="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$vid5&key=$api_key";
$jsonplaylistgetter5 = file_get_contents($json_viewgetter5);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonplaylistgetter5);
$vid5views=$listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

$json_viewgetter6="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$vid6&key=$api_key";
$jsonplaylistgetter6 = file_get_contents($json_viewgetter6);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonplaylistgetter6);
$vid6views=$listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

$json_viewgetter7="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$vid7&key=$api_key";
$jsonplaylistgetter7 = file_get_contents($json_viewgetter7);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonplaylistgetter7);
$vid7views=$listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;

$json_viewgetter8="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$vid8&key=$api_key";
$jsonplaylistgetter8 = file_get_contents($json_viewgetter8);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonplaylistgetter8);
$vid8views=$listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;




//Last Video Thumbnails 

$images = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$lastvidid."?v=2&alt=json"), true);
$images = $images['entry']['media$group']['media$thumbnail'];
$image  = $images[count($images)-4]['url'];

$maxurl = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$lastvidid."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl0 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid0."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl1 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid1."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl2 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid2."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl3 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid3."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl4 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid4."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl5 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid5."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl6 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid6."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl7 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid7."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl8 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid8."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$max    = get_headers($maxurl);

if (substr($max[0], 9, 3) !== '404') {
    $image = $maxurl;   
}


?>
```

Comment: Well you have 25 remote file_get_contents calls. You can reduce loading times by caching the results.

Comment: Or shall i try to change to jquery code... but never used jquery for the youtube api but i googleing for it. thanks for ur edit.

Comment: @DaveChen i got the problem.. i now put someids in one and its fast... the problem is the instagram api my server needs time to connect with the insta api.. if i use the cache option for instagram i need to w8 for 1h till a new picture gets updated..... cache is good... how can i check the respone time between my server using nginx and the instagram api request?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code a little bet and got not that much file_get_contents.
But i found out that the Instagram API is really slow. So if i integrate the
instagram API my page loaded really slow. If i use Jquery Code it works fast but, everyone can look into the code and see the script brackets and thats what i dont want.

```
<?php
//Instagram Getter

// use this instagram access token generator http://instagram.pixelunion.net/
$access_token="";
$photo_count=9;

$json_instalink="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=$access_token&count=$photo_count";
$jsoninsta = file_get_contents($json_instalink);
$objinsta = json_decode($jsoninsta);

//Link zu den Bildern
$imagelink1 = $objinsta->data[0]->link;
$imagelink2 = $objinsta->data[1]->link;
$imagelink3 = $objinsta->data[2]->link;
$imagelink4 = $objinsta->data[3]->link;
$imagelink5 = $objinsta->data[4]->link;
$imagelink6 = $objinsta->data[5]->link;
$imagelink7 = $objinsta->data[6]->link;
$imagelink8 = $objinsta->data[7]->link;
$imagelink9 = $objinsta->data[8]->link;


//Das Bild an sich
$profilelink1 = $objinsta->data[0]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink2 = $objinsta->data[1]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink3 = $objinsta->data[2]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink4 = $objinsta->data[3]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink5 = $objinsta->data[4]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink6 = $objinsta->data[5]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink7 = $objinsta->data[6]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink8 = $objinsta->data[7]->images->standard_resolution->url;
$profilelink9 = $objinsta->data[8]->images->standard_resolution->url;

//Channel and API Key
$channel_id = '';
$api_key = '';

//Channel Statistics
$json_statsurl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=$channel_id&key=$api_key";
$jsonstats = file_get_contents($json_statsurl);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonstats);
$subscriberCount = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->subscriberCount;

//Last Video ID/Title/Published/Thumbnails
$json_lastvidurl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=$api_key&channelId=$channel_id&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=10";
$jsonlastvid = file_get_contents($json_lastvidurl);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvid);

$lastvidid = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->id->videoId;
$lastvidtitle = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->title;
$lastvidpublished = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->snippet->publishedAt;
$maxurl = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$lastvidid."/maxresdefault.jpg";


//Playlist Videos 9 ID/Title/Published/Thumbnails
$vid0=$listFromYouTube->items[1]->id->videoId;
$vid1=$listFromYouTube->items[2]->id->videoId;
$vid2=$listFromYouTube->items[3]->id->videoId;
$vid3=$listFromYouTube->items[4]->id->videoId;
$vid4=$listFromYouTube->items[5]->id->videoId;
$vid5=$listFromYouTube->items[6]->id->videoId;
$vid6=$listFromYouTube->items[7]->id->videoId;
$vid7=$listFromYouTube->items[8]->id->videoId;
$vid8=$listFromYouTube->items[9]->id->videoId;

$vid0t=$listFromYouTube->items[1]->snippet->title;
$vid1t=$listFromYouTube->items[2]->snippet->title;
$vid2t=$listFromYouTube->items[3]->snippet->title;
$vid3t=$listFromYouTube->items[4]->snippet->title;
$vid4t=$listFromYouTube->items[5]->snippet->title;
$vid5t=$listFromYouTube->items[6]->snippet->title;
$vid6t=$listFromYouTube->items[7]->snippet->title;
$vid7t=$listFromYouTube->items[8]->snippet->title;
$vid8t=$listFromYouTube->items[9]->snippet->title;

$vid0published = $listFromYouTube->items[1]->snippet->publishedAt;
$vid1published = $listFromYouTube->items[2]->snippet->publishedAt;
$vid2published = $listFromYouTube->items[3]->snippet->publishedAt;
$vid3published = $listFromYouTube->items[4]->snippet->publishedAt;
$vid4published = $listFromYouTube->items[5]->snippet->publishedAt;
$vid5published = $listFromYouTube->items[6]->snippet->publishedAt;
$vid6published = $listFromYouTube->items[7]->snippet->publishedAt;
$vid7published = $listFromYouTube->items[8]->snippet->publishedAt;
$vid8published = $listFromYouTube->items[9]->snippet->publishedAt;

$vidurl0 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid0."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl1 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid1."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl2 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid2."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl3 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid3."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl4 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid4."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl5 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid5."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl6 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid6."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl7 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid7."/maxresdefault.jpg";
$vidurl8 = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/".$vid8."/maxresdefault.jpg";

//Last Video Views
$json_lastvidstatsurl="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=$lastvidid,$vid0,$vid1,$vid2,$vid3,$vid4,$vid5,$vid6,$vid7,$vid8&key=$api_key";
$jsonlastvidstats = file_get_contents($json_lastvidstatsurl);
$listFromYouTube=json_decode($jsonlastvidstats);
$lastvidviews = $listFromYouTube->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;
$vid0views = $listFromYouTube->items[1]->statistics->viewCount;
$vid1views = $listFromYouTube->items[2]->statistics->viewCount;
$vid2views = $listFromYouTube->items[3]->statistics->viewCount;
$vid3views = $listFromYouTube->items[4]->statistics->viewCount;
$vid4views = $listFromYouTube->items[5]->statistics->viewCount;
$vid5views = $listFromYouTube->items[6]->statistics->viewCount;
$vid6views = $listFromYouTube->items[7]->statistics->viewCount;
$vid7views = $listFromYouTube->items[8]->statistics->viewCount;
$vid8views = $listFromYouTube->items[9]->statistics->viewCount;

//Watchlink
$watchlink="http://undercover-gaming.de/youtube/video/";


?>
```